# How to fetch objects from results one by one without do .count

Tags: swift, realm

I need to fetch from Realm Results 20 objects or less. A database can be heavy, so Results.count is a long time for calling.

So, what I need is to fetch objects from Results one by one until I get 20 or until last object.

But, when I'm trying to fetch index after the last object it's throwing Realm exception 'Index x is out of bounds (must be less than x)'.

So, this one isn't working:

```
let searchResult = Ticket().get(filter: "base == nil && deleted == 0 AND orderPaidAt > 0 AND (\(query))").sorted(byKeyPath: "orderPaidAt")

for i in 0..<20 {
    if let ticket = searchResult[i] as? Ticket {
        ...
    } else {
        break
    }
}
```

If I'm trying to use `searchResult.count` or `searchResult.endIndex` it increases a time a lot, especially on old devices. That's why I want to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use prefix(maxLenght: Int) method to get a subCollection with specified maxLenght.
Example:

```
realm.objects(ObjectModel.self).prefix(20).count
```

Comment: It makes main query to freeze for 60 seconds, compare to previous situation it is 4 times slow.

Answer (score 0):

The results are lazily loaded, so you could loop through the results one by one, until the end, or until you hit a self-set count:

```
let searchResult = Ticket().get(filter: "base == nil && deleted == 0 AND orderPaidAt > 0 AND (\(query))").sorted(byKeyPath: "orderPaidAt")
var count = 0
for thisTicket in searchResult {
   // do something
   count += 1
   if count > 20 { break }
}
```

This way you are only loading the values that you need, and never calling `count` or accessing the results out of bounds.

Comment: Looks like `for something in somethings` execute .count, because it is working, but with same time for execution. :)